# Installing PyQt4 for Python 3 mac

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4

I'm having trouble getting PyQt4 to work with Python 3.  I was able to get PyQt5 to work but all the tutorials seem to be using PyQt4 for web scraping so it looks like I'm forced to use PyQt4.

I've followed the directions at

```
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html
```

but whenever I get to the 'make install' part everything is copied over to my Python 2.7 directory where it works for Python 2.7.

I tried setting the destination directory

```
python3 configure.py -destdir/Users/ryan/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```

but it still installed to the python 2 dir.  I also tried setting the python version

```
python3 configure.py --target-py-version 3.4
```

but it returns

```
configure.py: error: no such option: --target-py-version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh). Once brew installed, simply type the following commands in your terminal:

```
brew install sip --with-python3
brew install pyqt --with-python3
```

Comment: I had Python 2.7/3.4/3.5 installed, after removing 3.4 I was finally able to get this working using what you suggested along with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711594/pyqt4-on-mavericks-with-python-3

Comment: @RyanHalabi Good to hear. If you think the answer was usefull an upvote/accept would be nice