# PyQt4 in Mac OS X for Python 3 doesn't seem to work

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt4

I installed PyQT4 in Mac OS X El Capitan for Python 3 using the instructions given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21714509/1815288). The instructions gave the following commands:

```
brew install python3
brew install qt
brew install sip --with-python3
brew install pyqt --with-python3
```

which I run with no problems at all. I then added this line to my `.bashrc` file:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I verified Python 3 was running correcly. I also correctly evaluated the following code within Python 3:

```
import PyQT4
```

Now, when I try to run this simple program, nothing happens:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.show()
```

After running it, no window opens and nothing happens. I get no error or warning messages. Any ideas of what's going on in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. When you run your code, nothing is supposed to happen, and the application should immediately exit without any errors. Your example translated to C++ will behave identically, too.

Perhaps you wished to spin the event loop? `app.exec()` will do that.

Comment: @NVaughan Without a running event loop, GUI applications generally do nothing. `app.exec()` runs the event loop until the application is quit, allowing the window to be shown, processing the incoming events, etc. It's [documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exec).